# Find the set of numbers with the least sum such that no pair of numbers in the set has the same GCD

Tags: number-theory

I posted [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/find-a-set-of-10-numbers-such-that-all-pairs-have-a-different-gcf) over at CodeGolf.SE, and it seemed like an interesting math problem in general (albeit one in which computers could help with the search).

The problem statement is as follows:

> For some $n$, find the set of numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$ such that the numbers obtained by taking the greatest common factor of each pair of numbers in the set are all distinct, and the sum of all the numbers in the set is the least possible.

In the CodeGolf.SE problem, I set $n = 10$, and we've found a solution that is pretty good, but doesn't seem to be optimal, as the principle used in generating the numbers for that solution produce a suboptimal result when $n = 4$.

Is there a general formula for this type of question? If so, can you prove that it's optimal?

Answer (score 1):

A slow algorithm that surely returns an optimal solution is just to try all possibilities.

Set $s = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

Start Loop

Generate all sets $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = s$.

Check whether there is a set with $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=\gcd(a_k,a_l)$ only for $i=k, j=l$ or $i=l, j=k$.

If not then Set s = s + 1 and goto Start Loop Else done.

Comment: While this does work, it becomes awfully slow for values larger than 10, and I was wondering whether there was a more deterministic algorithm.

Comment: That is a different question I guess.